# Create new Grid in Sitecore Experience Accelerator

Tags: sxa

I am using `Sitecore Experience Accelerator 1.4` and I do not want to use `Bootstrap, Foundation or Grid960`. I have my `custom CSS framework`. Anyone can provide me a solution that how I can add a new Grid?

Comment: According to this page you can create your own grid: https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_accelerator/getting_started_with_sxa/layout/the_grid_layout 'SXA supports integrating other grid frameworks and you can also build your own.' I'm not exactly sure how you go about doing this though as can't find any docs on it. However it looks like you might need to add to the base themes here: /sitecore/Media Library/Base Themes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

<strike>It is easy.</strike> The implementation steps are low complexity.
See how bootstrap is configured

## Create Grid Theme

**Example:**

`/sitecore/media library/Feature/Experience Accelerator/Bootstrap/Bootstrap`

**Why/What?**

It is your custom grid theme. The most important thing is to include your css file with all your grid classes

## Create Grid Definition

**Example:**

`/sitecore/system/Settings/Feature/Experience Accelerator/Bootstrap/Grid Definition`

**Why/What?**

This item contains children which defines your devices (Phone, Desktop). Each device can have different properties (Size, Push, Pull, Offset) and each property can have different values (css classes, for example `col-xs-1` for `Phone Device->Size->1`, you will use your grid classes here)

**Fields:**

- `RenderingParametersFieldType` - I assume you are not doing anything custom here, so you can use default field renderer: `Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Grid.Fields.FieldRenderers.GridRenderingParametersFieldRenderer, Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Grid`. Once you fill this field and save an item you should see `DefaultGridParameters` rendering your configuration.
- `DefaultGridParameters` - provide default values here
- `Grid Theme` - link to your grid theme defined in **step 1**
- `GridFieldParserType` - link in first point, use default: `Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Grid.Parser.GridFieldParser,Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Grid` if you are not going to customize anything.

  - `GridBodyViewPath` - path to your `cshtml` file which contains your grid layout. Remember to include all necessary placeholders (`header`, `main`, `footer`)

## Create Scaffolding Setup

**Example:**

`/sitecore/system/Settings/Feature/Experience Accelerator/Bootstrap/Grid Setup`

**Why/What?**

This item contains only link to a `Grid Definition` and `Name` that will appear in a new *Site Dialog* in the tab with grid selection

Comment: I think the thing I hate the most about SXA is how everyone writing about it keep saying "It is easy". It's easy when you are use to it, just like it's easy for me to perform Sub-Zero MkII Fatality, but for someone who start with SXA, it's everything but easy.

Comment: I would agree with @SimonArnold