# How to enable the SXA toolbox in custom Grid?

Tags: sxa

I have created the custom Grid, as per the steps mentioned in the [link](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/6463/create-new-grid-in-sitecore-experience-accelerator)

When I am using my custom grid SXA Toolbox is not loading, Editing, Designing and Drag & drop options are enabled in the View Ribbon

How to enable the SXA toolbox in custom Grid?

Comment: Can you please check browser console? Are there any errors?

Comment: I didn't get any errors in the browser console. I have resolved this issue and added the answer.

Answer (score 1):

After doing some research I have resolved the above issue. In my custom grid's body view cshtml, I removed the Wrapper id from the div element because of that toolbox is not rendered in the experience editor.

Toolbox is rendered above the wrapper element so if it's not present it won't be rendered in the experience editor.