# How to remove the references to bootstrap in SXA?

Tags: sxa

I created an own theme for SXA incl. Gridding, the problem is, that SXA is still calling bootstrap.css, which overrides all the styles that I made in my own theme. Is there is a possibility to disable the Sitecore calls to bootstrap?

Comment: If your theme loads after the base themes, you should have no issue overriding the bootstrap styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap will be your grid system (it's the default). If you want to remove all references to bootstrap, I think you need to select another grid system (currenly you can select Bootstrap, Foundation or Grid960) or create your own.

Info on the grid systems: https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_accelerator/building_the_layout/structure/the_grid_settings

How to create your own: [Create new Grid in Sitecore Experience Accelerator](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/6463/create-new-grid-in-sitecore-experience-accelerator)

Comment: That is the best approach, create a new grid and assign it to the site needed. Thanks